# Is there a way to use itertools in python to clean up nested iterations?

Tags: python, iterator, nested-loops, python-itertools

Let's say I have the following code:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,4,6]
c = [3,5,7]

for i in a:
  for j in b:
    for k in c:
      print i * j * k
```

Is there a way I can consolidate an iterator in one line instead of making it nested?

Answer (score 11):

Use `itertools.product` within a list comprehension:

```
In [1]: from itertools import product
In [5]: [i*j*k for i, j, k in product(a, b, c)]
Out[5]: 
[6,
 10,
 14,
 12,
 20,
 28,
 18,
 30,
 42,
 12,
 20,
 28,
 24,
 40,
 56,
 36,
 60,
 84,
 18,
 30,
 42,
 36,
 60,
 84,
 54,
 90,
 126]
```

Comment: Thanks! And I'm assuming that the i, j, and k are respective to the ordering of what's defined in the product?

Comment: @Skorpius Yes, you're correct.